# Solving a momentum problem without the assumption

Tags: homework-and-exercises, momentum

I encountered the problem in Physics HRK:

> A stream of bullets whose mass m is each $3.8$ g is fired horizontally
> with a speed v of $1100 \frac{m}{s}$ into a large wooden block of mass that is
> initially at rest on a horizontal table. If the block
> is free to slide without friction across the table, what speed will it
> acquire after it has absorbed eight bullets?

The solution is already written in the book. It's pretty simple, however, it assumes that all $8$ bullets are in flight before the first bullet strikes the block. The next paragraph intrigues me:

> For simplicity in solving this problem, we have assumed that the
> bullets are fired so rapidly that all eight are in flight before the
> first bullet strikes the block. Can you solve this problem without
> making this assumption?

Wouldn't it be the same?

---

Edit: This is the book's solution simplified:

The initial (horizontal) momentum, measured while the
bullets are still in flight and the block is at rest, is
$P_{ix}=N(mv)$
in which $mv$ is the momentum of an individual bullet and $N=8$.
The final horizontal momentum, measured when all the bullets are
in the block and the block is sliding over the table with horizontal
velocity V, is
$$P_{fx} = (M+Nm)V$$
Conservation of momentum requires that
$$P_{ix} = P_{fx}$$
Solving for $V$ yields $V = 2.8 \frac{m}{s}$

Comment: *"Wouldn't it be the same?"* I would certainly think so, but perhaps you should describe the book's solution so that we can see whether that solution somehow uses the assumption that the bullets take flight before any of them hits the block.

Comment: @DanielSank Ok.

Comment: Yes it is the same - each bullet adds mass $m$ and momentum $mv$ to the sliding block regardless of when they are fired. If you had a long enough table you could fire the bullets at a rate of one an hour and still get the same final velocity for the block.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to consider a series of incidents taking place.
When the first bullet strikes

- $$P_{f 1} = (M+m)V1=mv$$

---

After this as the mass adds to the block

- $$P_{f2} = (M+2m)V2=mv+(M+m)V1$$

.....`v is initial velocity of bullet

---

And so on you can calculate

`

Comment: This has nothing to do with when the bullets are fired, which is the crux of the OP's question.

Comment: Isnt the op asking for the situation when bulletes are not moving together rather individually